# Scanner requests input twice

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. I'm trying to make an exercise.

> P3.3 Write a program that reads an integer and prints how many digits
>   the number has, by checking whether the number is ≥ 10, ≥ 100, and so
>   on. (Assume that all integers are less than ten billion.) If the
>   number is negative, first multiply it with –1.

The problem is : I see that I have to enter twice an enter before I get the output. I know that it has to do with  the code:

```
if(in.hasNextInt()){
    int number = in.nextInt();
}
```

But what should I change in this case to just have one input instead of 2?
Thanks in advance.

```
package week2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P3_3_Digits {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Voer een getal in: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();


    if(in.hasNextInt()){

        in.close();

    if(number < 0){
        number = number * -1;

        if(number >= 10 && number < 100){
            System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 2 digits.");
            }

        else if(number >= 100 && number < 1000){
                System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 3 digits.");
        }
        else if(number >= 1000 && number < 10000){
            System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 4 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 10000 && number < 100000){
            System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 5 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 100000 && number < 1000000){
            System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 6 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 1000000 && number < 10000000){
            System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 7 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 10000000 && number < 100000000){
            System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 8 digits.");

    }





    }

    else {
        if(number >= 10 && number < 100){
            System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 2 digits.");
            }

        else if(number >= 100 && number < 1000){
                System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 3 digits.");
        }
        else if(number >= 1000 && number < 10000){
            System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 4 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 10000 && number < 100000){
            System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 5 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 100000 && number < 1000000){
            System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 6 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 1000000 && number < 10000000){
            System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 7 digits.");
    }
        else if(number >= 10000000 && number < 100000000){
            System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 8 digits.");
    }

    }
    }
    else { System.out.println(" Onjuiste invoer. Voer een getal in.");

}
}

}
```

Comment: Little trick to count digits   int length = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);

Comment: thnx for this trick!

Comment: removed unrelated tag, formatted citation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly refer to the [hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--).

> `public boolean hasNextInt()` Returns true if the next token in this
>   scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default
>   radix using the nextInt() method. The scanner does not advance past
>   any input.

`if(in.hasNextInt()){` condition will be evaluated `true` or `false` when **second input** will be provided. **And this condition will be true only when second input can be interpreted as an int value.**

So remove `if(in.hasNextInt()){` from your code then it will be all set.

**Corrected code is given below-:**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Voer een getal in: ");

if (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int number = in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    if (number < 0) {
    number = number * -1;

    if (number >= 10 && number < 100) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 2 digits.");
    }

    else if (number >= 100 && number < 1000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 3 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 1000 && number < 10000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 4 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 10000 && number < 100000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 5 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 100000 && number < 1000000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 6 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 1000000 && number < 10000000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 7 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 10000000 && number < 100000000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal -" + number + " heeft 8 digits.");

    }

    } else {
    if (number >= 10 && number < 100) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 2 digits.");
    }

    else if (number >= 100 && number < 1000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 3 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 1000 && number < 10000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 4 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 10000 && number < 100000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 5 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 100000 && number < 1000000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 6 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 1000000 && number < 10000000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 7 digits.");
    } else if (number >= 10000000 && number < 100000000) {
        System.out.println("Het getal " + number + " heeft 8 digits.");
    }

    }
} else {
     System.out.println(" Onjuiste invoer. Voer een getal in.");
}
```

**Edit-:** `int number = in.nextInt();` line of code has been moved to inside `if(in.hasNextInt()){` condition.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to say:
If the user give as input: "Hello" , it should give the following:   
  else { System.out.println(" Onjuiste invoer. Voer een getal in."); 
an integer is required.

Comment: @Noor , I have updated the code as per your requirement. `int number = in.nextInt();` line of code has been moved inside `if(in.hasNextInt()){` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code in such way:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Voer een getal in: ");

        String s = in.nextLine();
        boolean isNumeric = s.chars().allMatch( Character::isDigit );

        while (!isNumeric) {
            System.out.println(" Onjuiste invoer. Voer een getal in.");
            s = in.nextLine();
            isNumeric = s.chars().allMatch( Character::isDigit );
        }

        int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
        in.close();

//        if (number < 0) {      ...

    }
```

Comment: In this case I cannot use a negative digit.

Comment: Ok, try isNumeric = s.matches("^-?([0-9]+)$"); (should be changed in two places)